# Finalizer Throws Random Exceptions, Raises Random Errors, Hangs App

Tags: .net, c++-cli, destructor, finalizer

I have a class in C++/CLI that uses unmanaged resources (a HANDLE for a native thread (i.e. from CreateThread()) and an LPVOID for a fiber from CreateFiber/ConvertThreadToFiber).

Under the advice I got from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177197.aspx) I'm cleaning up the unmanaged resources in the finalizer (!Fiber()), and the destructor (~Fiber()) is calling the finalizer.

Here's the code:

```
Fiber::~Fiber () {

    this->!Fiber();

}


Fiber::!Fiber () {

    if (thread!=NULL) {

        delete thread;
        thread=NULL;

    }

    if (fiber!=NULL) {

        DeleteFiber(fiber);
        fiber=NULL;

    }

}
```

I have a test app that creates two fibers, tests them, and then disposes them as it's done with them.  The first one is disposed just fine.  The last one is disposed as the last line of the program, and it crashes out in one of three different ways:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write
 protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at DeleteFiber(Void* )
   at System.Threading.Fiber.!Fiber()
   at System.Threading.Fiber.Dispose(Boolean )
   at System.Threading.Fiber.Finalize()
```

That error can also come from the line:

```
delete thread;
```

As well.

It may also crash with an OutOfMemoryException, or by hanging for a while, saying that the program experienced a stack overflow, and then hanging the console (I have to close cmd.exe and restart it to recover).

If I comment the destructor/finalizer out, and run the program, it runs perfectly, but that's not an option because I don't want unmanaged resources hanging around until the program ends...

Comment: What does the DeleteFiber() method look like?

Comment: [Like this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682556(v=VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If `thread` is a `HANDLE`, you clean it up with `CloseHandle(thread)`, not `delete thread`.
2. You should initialize `thread` and `fiber` to `NULL` in `Fiber`'s constructor, to maintain the invariants of the class.
3. You can't call `DeleteFiber` on the currently executing fiber, unless you want to terminate the thread. You clean it up by calling [`ConvertFiberToThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Interesting.  That does not, however, fix the problem -- I'm still getting AccessViolationExceptions from DeleteFiber.

Comment: The constructor does both of the things you mention in #2.  I'm calling Dispose() from another fiber (in the first case), and then from the Main () method of the C# program (which is in another thread, in the second case).

Comment: #3 was the -- indirect -- solution.  Attempting to clean up a fiber which was made out of a thread by cleaning up the thread first invalidates the fiber.  The solution was to alter the code so that `DeleteFiber` is only executed if `thread` is `NULL`.